# Is Spring.Threading.Helpers still supported?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am converting some old C# code, and it has a CountDownLatch using a package called Spring.Threading.Helpers.  The odd thing is that I can't find this package on Google - so a) is it still supported?  And, if so, where is it documented?  b) What I really want to do is wait for a count to get to zero, but interrupt every so many msecs.  Would it just be simpler to set up another thread, and do WaitOnes on an Event specifying an interval?  TIA

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is part of spring.net - www.springframework.net - so my better question is: is spring.net a standard part (?) of Microsoft Visual C#?